# Reading input from file and populating array to store data for later use

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, vector

I'm trying to make multiple arrays of maximum size 10 that hold the contents of an input file. Suppose the file is formatted like:

```
1 3 2 4 0 5 8 -3
3 1 4 6 0 3
4 83 2 12 1 3
4 30 4 -2
```

Where each line cannot exceed more than 10 integers.

```
void read_input(ifstream &file)
{
    vector<array<int, 10> > main_array;

    while(!(file.eof()))
    {
        int idx = 0;
        string values;
        array<int, 10> part_array;

        getline(file, values);
        istringstream inStream;
        inStream.str(values);

        while((inStream >> part_array[idx++]).good() == true);
        main_array.push_back(part_array);

        file.ignore();
    }

    for(auto it = main_array.begin(); it != main_array.end(); it++)
    {
        for(auto& s: *it)
        {
            cout << s <<  " ";
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
}
```

This gives me the output:

```
1 3 2 4 0 5 8 -3 0 6164240
1 4 6 0 3 5 8 -3 0 6164240
83 2 12 1 3 5 8 -3 0 6164240
30 4 -2 1 3 5 8 -3 0 6164240
```

Which is clearly wrong. I know this may have to do with me iterating over array elements that aren't initialized, but how can I avoid this error? Just as a note, it is essentially that I use arrays to hold the values at each line in the file. That is, one array must handle the integers in the first line; another in the second line...

Comment: `while(!(file.eof()))` is broken - move `string values;` before and change to `while (getline(file, values))`....

Comment: I'm still missing the first value of each row after the first row. Any ideas why this is?

Comment: You are missing values because you told it to `ignore` them

Comment: well, that'd be this: `file.ignore();`

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
 vector<vector<int> > main_array;
```

instead of an array - then just read items from input and push them  (push_back) into the "inner" vector - this way you won't have uninitialized array elements at the end in case when data row is shorter than 10 elements.

Full solution may look like this (I've kept some parts of your original code for consistency):

```
using namespace std;

void read_input(ifstream &file)
{
    vector<vector<int> > main_array;

    string line;    //buffer for single line read from file 
    // reading part
    while(getline(file, line))
    {       
        stringstream inStream(line);
        vector<int> row;    //single row buffer
        int val = 0;
        while(inStream >> val)
        {
            row.push_back(val);
        }       
        main_array.push_back(row);
    }   

    //display part
    for(auto it = main_array.begin(), end = main_array.end(); it != end; ++it)
    {
        for(auto& s: *it)
        {
            cout << s <<  " ";
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're using a non C++11 standard compiler don't forget about that space between brackets (just like kamilm put it there). If you're C++11 you can drop it.

Answer (score 2):

Use this if you find it useful,

```
void readData(ifstream &inf)
{
    string str;
    vector<vector<int>> intArr;

    while (getline(inf, str))
    {
        stringstream ss(str);
        int i;
        vector<int> a;
        while (ss >> i)
        {
            a.push_back(i);
        }
        intArr.push_back(a);
    }
}
```

You shouldn't use `eof()` to check end of file.

Answer (score 1):

std::array is a container that encapsulates constant size arrays., so by declaring with `array<int, 10>` there are already 10 integers in the array. You need to use vector instead, and change your loop

```
 while((inStream >> part_array[idx++]).good() == true);
```

to

```
 bool good = true;
 while(idx <10 ) {
     int v;
     if(!(inStream >> v).good() ) break;
     idx++;
     part_array.push_back(v); //now a vector
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have used an `array` with 10 elements but you know there may be fewer than ten items. It would be better to use a vector, and `push_back` what you have.

Aside from that, there are a variety of potential problems with the code. If you send it a bad `ifstream` it gets stuck in a loop.

`while(!(file.eof()))` is asking for trouble.

Next, `file.ignore();` then ignores the first items of each line. If you change to use a vector of vectors as people have said, use `while(getline(file, values))` instead of using the `eof` check and remove the `ignore` it should work.

Answer (score -1):

Change this line

```
array<int, 10> part_array;
```

to

```
array<int, 10> part_array = {};
```

Comment: I seem to be missing the first value of each row after the first row. Can you spot why that is?